# kusama upload/download bandwidth speed so low

Tags: kusama, substrate-node, validator, api, nodes

I'm running a Kusama node with a actual network speed ranging from over 100MB/s to 500MB/s on both sides.
However, I'm facing issues with slow block propagation time and low upload/download bandwidth speeds(**under 100kB/s**) on my node, even though I have a gigabyte network. What could be causing this problem, and how can I optimize my node's performance to improve these issues?

Comment: Where geographically is your node running? You can see there are geographic clusters of nodes: https://telemetry.polkadot.io/#map/0xb0a8d493285c2df73290dfb7e61f870f17b41801197a149ca93654499ea3dafe

Comment: Even if you have a lot of bandwidth, the nodes you're connected to may not which can cause your bandwidth utilization to be a fraction of the available bandwidth. And as Bruno already alluded to, your geographical location is also a factor.

Answer (score -1):

- Do you use Paritydb? Do you sync an archive node (state history)?
- Do you use a nvme SSD disk?
- Did you check the metrics of your disk during sync (avg read/write speed)?
- What is your CPU?

Comment: I used polkachu snapshots DB and I use 1TB SSD NVME, it seems working well and cpu is 8core 16thread. sometimes, upload/download bandwidth speed is over 1MB/s when its high and under 100kB/s when it`s low. very volatile....... what can cause this....

Comment: - Do you use Paritydb or Rocksdb? Do you sync an archive node (state history)? Or provide the full CLI command that you use to run the nodeю What are average read/write speeds (utilization) of your disk during sync? What is the model of your CPU?

Comment: This may be better as a comment